# how to display a message box using openGL in visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, graphics

How to display a message box on the window which is created when we execute a visual c++ program using openGL.
Specifically i want to display a message and one "OK" button.So when the user clicks on OK button it should resume to the same state as it was before that message box.

Thank you

Comment: If you want a separate window with a message box, OpenGL doesn't handle things like that. You can just create a window like usual. If you want it in the same window, just draw a box in OpenGL and handle button presses to check if it was hit

Comment: is there any built in library function with which we can directly call that function and draw a message box

Answer (score 1):

You said Visual C++; so I'd use something like this:

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"Description", L"Info",
  MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
```

It's defined in `<winuser.h>` which should automatically be included with `<windows.h>`, I think.

Comment: it is not working. Can you please give me the executable code for the same.

Comment: What is it doing?  It doesn't compile?